# How to load both static and Api Response Tags in ngTagsInput in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

Need help to load first the static tags and hit backend API simultaneously to get suggestion list as a part of autocomplete loadTags function as it works only for the first return of the function so I am either able to hit for backend and return the list or I am able to return the static list;

```
  function loadTags(query) {
    myLocalTags = _.merge(filteredBasicTags, filteredAdvTags);

    apiService.getBackendTags(query).then(function(response) {
      myLocalTags = _.values(_.merge(myLocalTags, response.data));
      return myLocalTags;
    });
   //so either I am able to return the apiService Response or the myLocalTags Data for the autocomplete suggestions.

    return myLocalTags;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.autocompleteSuggestions = _.merge(filteredBasicTags, filteredAdvTags);

apiService.getBackendTags(query).then(function(response) {
      myLocalTags = _.values(_.merge(myLocalTags, response.data));
      $scope.autocompleteSuggestions = myLocalTags;
    });
```